# Render JSON from Rails controller into html script view partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my view I want to create a javascript object that matches my ruby object `current_user`

Seems like a good solution instead of making an extra request to `/users/me`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This took me longer than it should have:

```
<script>
  window.current_user = <%= raw(current_user.to_json) %>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for doing a self-answered question for this! It also took me longer than it should have.

Answer (score 0):

**send json from controller to view**

```
def show_user_categories
     @categories= current_users.categories.map do |c|
      { :id => c.id,:name => c.title}
    end   
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @categories}
    end
 end
```

**fetch the json in view**

```
   <%= javascript_tag do%>
     window.categories= <%=raw @categories.to_json %>;

    <%end%>
```

**and then use it in js script**

```
var markers=[];
 $.each(categories, function(index) {
     //creating js array which can be used in js script
     //using the id/title passed from controller code                 
     markers.push([categories[index]['id'],categories[index]['title']]);

 });
```